# blank screen with x shape pointer after installing ubuntu 13.10

Tags: graphics

Installed ubuntu and it was showing low graphics so updated by the command

```
 sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

as told in

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Now screen shows only blank screen.with x shape pointer.What to do now?

My laptop hp n003tx